# Rescanning and assigning variable in while loop

Tags: c

I am new to coding so I apologize for any ignorance, but I am running into two issue with my program. The goal is to prompt the user to enter a test number, run the test, and output whether the number is "perfect". After, the user is prompted to continue testing a new number or end the program. I am running into two issues. 1. No matter if 'y' or 'n' is entered, the while loop continues to run. 2. userInput does not get reassigned and continues to run with the same input value as the first input. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void perfectNumber(int userInput) {

    int divisor = 0;
    int i;
    int totalSum = 0;
    char cont;

    for (i = 1; i < userInput; i++) {
        divisor = userInput % i;
        if (divisor == 0) {
            totalSum = totalSum + i;
        }
    }

    if (totalSum == userInput) {
        printf("Number %d is perfect\n", userInput);
    }
    else {
        printf("Number %d is not perfect\n", userInput);
    }
    printf("Do you want to continue (y/n)?  ");
    scanf("%c\n", &cont);
}

int main(void) {
    int userInput;
    char cont = 'y';

    while (cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y') {
        printf("Enter a perfect number:  ");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
        perfectNumber(userInput);
    }
    printf("Goodbye\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Does the code compile? Please provide a [mcve] so people can better help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you think the `cont` is the only one variable.

The truth is you have two `cont` variables and only thing they share is the same name.  They’re two different variables with unique adresses.

One belongs to main function, other one belongs to perfectNumber function.

How about returning that unique `cont` variable ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
char perfectNumber(int userInput) {
    int divisor = 0;
    int i;
    int totalSum = 0;
    char cont;

    for (i = 1; i < userInput; i++) {
        divisor = userInput % i;
        if (divisor == 0) {
            totalSum = totalSum + i;
        }
    }

    if (totalSum == userInput) {
        printf("Number %d is perfect\n", userInput);
    }
    else {
        printf("Number %d is not perfect\n", userInput);
    }
    printf("Do you want to continue (y/n)?  ");
    scanf(" %c", &cont);
    return cont;
}

int main(void) {
    int userInput;
    char cont = 'y';

    while (cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y') {
        printf("Enter a perfect number:  ");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
        cont = perfectNumber(userInput);
    }
    printf("Goodbye\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Note that you were missing #include guard, I added it.

Comment: I see exactly what you mean, i made the necessary changes and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `cont` in `main` (which is not the same as the `cont` in `perfectNumber`) is never changed inside the loop, and the loop guard is only dependent on that `cont`.  Similar thing w/ the two `userInput`s.